# Hikari CP (Spring Boot) Connection Recovery Problem After DB Failure

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, hikaricp

We have several microservices build on Spring Boot (2.2.4) and Hikari CP (3.4.2) with PostgreSQL.

Recently we have faced DB failure around 30 seconds. After the connections are lost some of the containers are failed to recover connections while others which has exactly the same configuration and application are just fine. Unfortunately we don't have the log indicating the pool sizes(idle active waiting) on time of the error.

We have received some broken pipe and connection lost errors on all containers when the connections are lost. After DB recovery we got the following exception only on some (2/18) containers that are failed to recover.

**StackTrace:**

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:402)   ... 20 moreCaused by: 
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.  at
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:689)   at
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:196)    at 
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:161)    at
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128) at 
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)    at 
org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38)    at
org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:104)  
... 30 moreCaused by:org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.    at 
org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.checkClosed(PgConnection.java:857) at 
org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.setNetworkTimeout(PgConnection.java:1639)  at 
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setNetworkTimeout(PoolBase.java:556)    at 
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.isConnectionAlive(PoolBase.java:169)    at 
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:185)    ... 35 more
```

we have seen similar(on the same system) situations and tests where the DB failovers and connections are restored on Hikari without any problem. But in this case one of the containers are restored by itself after 1 hour and others after restart.

As far as we know Hikari is not returning the broken connections on the pool and evicts them from the pool after marked as broken or closed. Any ideas what might happened to those containers while the others(exactly same image and configuration) are just fine.

PS: we cannot reproduce the problem.

**Hikari configuration:**

allowPoolSuspension.............false
connectionInitSql...............none
connectionTestQuery.............none
connectionTimeout...............30000
idleTimeout.....................600000
initializationFailTimeout.......1
isolateInternalQueries..........false
leakDetectionThreshold..........0
maxLifetime.....................1800000
maximumPoolSize.................15
minimumIdle.....................15
validationTimeout...............5000

Answer (score 0):

You can configure something like:

```
connectionTestQuery=select 1
```

This way Hikari tests that the connection is still alive before handling it over to Hibernate.

Comment: Hi, from the Hikari documentation it is intended for the legacy drivers which is not the case for us.
connectionTestQuery
If your driver supports JDBC4 we strongly recommend not setting this property. This is for "legacy" drivers that do not support the JDBC4 Connection.isValid() API. This is the query that will be executed just before a connection is given to you from the pool to validate that the connection to the database is still alive. Again, try running the pool without this property, HikariCP will log an error if your driver is not JDBC4 compliant to let you know. Default: none

Comment: Interesting, thanks for this. We had a similar problem with MySQL and adding `connectionTestQuery` helped a lot so now I'm not sure what happened